# Add role to user while login from external Provider like Google in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I have implemented External login provider in my project using Asp.net Identity.

And it's working fine but now I want to assign a Role to the user who has logged in through those external Provider.

For example I want to assign or add user to a role "User" to the person who has used its Google/Facebook account to access my site.

Comment: you can assign role in external login block for logged in user.

Comment: @Komal can you show me how to do this?Do you have any sample code?

Comment: can you demonstrate your up-to tried code?

Answer (score 2):

Inside Controllers/AccountController there is a method called ExternalLoginConfirmation.

That looks like below

```
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

add a call to `result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "User");`
like below:

```
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "User");
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```